# Can't access instance of form created by the constructor of the current form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

In my main form's constructor i have:

```
itemDisplay newForm = new itemDisplay();
newForm.Show();
```

elsewhere in the form i have a `textbox_textchanged` event where i am trying to reference a method in `newForm` but it won't let me access the instance much less the methods within it.  The constructor is public what else am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the newly created form as a module-level variable. Something like this:

```
private itemDisplay newForm = new itemDisplay();

public my_main_form()
{
    newForm.Show();
}
```

Then you should able to access `newForm` anywhere from in the main form.

Comment: Yup there it is, i knew it was something stupid simple that i was missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create instance of class below

```
private itemDisplay newForm;

public my_main_form()
{
    newForm = new itemDisplay();
    newForm.Show();
}
```